# Prestashop 1.6 admin page not loading templates, displayAdminCustomers hook error

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.1.17.

When I go to Customers menu in the back office and I click on "View" for any customer from the list, the page is loaded with unformatted text. Besides, I cannot see any other templates like the header or the footer. After inspecting elements there are no errors in the console, and I don't see anything in the head tag.

However, I see an error in the information at the end of the page (see the picture):

[image]

On the other hand, if I click on "Edit" for any customer from the list the page loads correctly.

Finally, after some tests, I could realize that the problem is the hook called "displayAdminCustomers", so I commented out this code until I fix the bug.

```
    {* display hook specified to this page : AdminCustomers *}
    {*{hook h="displayAdminCustomers" id_customer=$customer->id|intval}*}
```

Comment: It's not a default hook. Do you have any module installed on that hook? If yes, it can be a problem with the module

Comment: @AlexanderGrosul I don't know if I have a module installed on that hook. If so, maybe I could just leave it commented out? At least it seems it works well like this.

Comment: you can check whether you have any module in a hook or not in your admin panel  Modules and Services -> Positions and search for your hook, if it exists and has some modules then the problem could be in one of them

Comment: That was the issue. I just unhooked all the modules from that hook.